# Element wise concatenation of a list of lists with different lengths

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a sample list of lists like:

```
lol = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9,0,11],[21]]
```

the expected combined list is:

```
cl = [1,5,7,21,2,6,8,3,9,4,0,11]
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this preferably without nested for loops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

lol = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 0, 11], [21]]

out = [i for v in zip_longest(*lol) for i in v if not i is None]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[1, 5, 7, 21, 2, 6, 8, 3, 9, 4, 0, 11]
```

Answer (score 2):

itertools is your friend. Use `zip_longest` to zip ignoring the differing lengths,  chain it to flatten the zipped lists, and then just filter the `None`s.

```
lol = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9,0,11],[21]]
print([x for x in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.zip_longest(*lol)) if x is not None])
```

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps, a generator version of `zip_longest` is available as `more_itertools.interleave_longest`.

```
from more_itertools import interleave_longest, take

lol = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 0, 11], [21]]
gen_from_lol = interleave_longest(*lol)

print(next(gen_from_lol), next(gen_from_lol))
print(take(6, gen_from_lol))
print(next(gen_from_lol))
print(next(gen_from_lol), next(gen_from_lol))
```

Output

```
1 5
[7, 21, 2, 6, 8, 3]
9
4 0
```

Note that `interleave_longest(*iterables)` is the basically the same as `chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(*iterables))`